# Hibernate related object not available?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got issues with my hibernate query. There are two classes, `Wohnung` and `Kosten`. Each `Kosten` has a relation to a `Wohnung`.

In my controller, `kosten.getWohnung()` returns `null`. It looks as Hibernate did not select the related `Wohnung`.

This is the method of my `KostenDao`. I assume that I do have to change the query?

```
public Kosten findById(int id) {
    return (Kosten) getSession().createQuery("from Kosten k where k.id = " + id).uniqueResult();
}
```

for better understanding, here is part of my `Kosten` model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="WNG_KOSTEN")
public class Kosten {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;

//  @Column(name = "INSERT_DT", nullable = false)
//  @Value("${props.insertDt:SYSDATE}")
//  protected java.util.Date insertDt;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="WOHNUNG_ID")
    private Wohnung wohnung;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EAGER` fetch type, `FetchType.LAZY` is the default fetch type for all Hibernate relationships.

```
@ManyToOne (fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name="WOHNUNG_ID")
private Wohnung wohnung;
```